# Read from file to char array, C

Tags: c, linux, optimization, valgrind, indentation

I'm having some issues with this code and would mind to get a little help. This function reads from file to the dynamically allocated memory

Thanks @JonathanLeffler for help - function indent works perfectly! But one more issue appeared: with function read_file, that reads from file to char array, that is later passed to the indent.

=========================================================================

```
//--------------- read_file valgrind validations --------------------
==396== 144 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 62 of 66 
==396==    at 0x4C2AD10: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) 
==396==    by 0x401AC1: read_file (polisher.c:24) 
==396==    by 0x4025CE: test_indent (test_source.c:174) 
==396==    by 0x406BC7: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402C67: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402902: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==
```

=====================================================

```
char *read_file(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!f)
        return NULL;
    int n = 0, c = 0;
    char *a = NULL;
    c = fgetc(f);
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        n++;
        c = fgetc(f);
    }
    freopen(filename, "r", f);
    a = calloc(n + 1, sizeof(char));
    c = fgetc(f);
    n = 0;
    while(c != EOF)
    {
        a[n] = c;
        n++;
        c = fgetc(f);
    }
    a[n] = '\0';
    fclose(f);
    return a;
}
```

================================================================

```
START_TEST(test_indent)
{
    char *str = read_file("testifile.c");
    if (!str) str = read_file("test/testifile.c");
    if (!str) {
        fail("[M6.01.c] read_file(\"testifile.c\") returned NULL");
    }
    char *res = indent(str, "    ");
    if (!res) {
        free(str);
        free(res);
        fail("[M6.01.c] indent(\"testifile.c\") returned NULL");
    }

    char buf[OUTPUTLEN];
    if (mycompare_new(res, ref61c, buf, OUTPUTLEN)) {
        free(res);
        free(str);
        fail("[M6.01.c] Invalid string from indent(\"testifile.c\"): %s", buf);
    }
    free(str);
    free(res);
    test_complete();
}
END_TEST
```

Comment: What is the error you get for first question ? For valgrind output, can you point which line you get error (which line of code is the line 116, 127, ...) ?

Comment: @Garf365 `strncpy(dest + dest_offset, pad, pad_len + 1);` is 116. `dest[dest_offset++] = c; ` is 127. When I try to send this function to server it says "Early exit with return value 1". The error message for the first question is "Received signal: SIGABRT (Aborted). For main, PID 9424"

Comment: Please, edit your question to add this information. Also, check every time function `indent` is mentioned into valgrind output and add information about line for each mentioned line

Comment: @Garf365 OK, done.

Comment: The error messages say "you allocated 144 bytes (e.g. `char *space = malloc(144);`) and then you tried to write to `space[144]` which is not part of the allocated space.  This is not allowed, of course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So what should I change in the code to avoid this?

Comment: Please do **not** edit the question so that the answer is no longer relevant.  Since `read_file()` was not mentioned in the original question, it should not be added later.  If you have a new question about a new function (as it seem you do), then you should ask a new question.  The cost per question is really quite reasonable!  If you must edit this question, then do so as a pure addition, adding the new code and the new Valgrind complaints as extra material without damaging the original material.  (That means you can edit the original if need be, but you shouldn't spoil it.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler unfortunately I'll have to wait 2 days to ask a new question... Deadline of this function is on 08/31

Comment: Oh, there's a rate limit for asking new questions?  It was a long time ago that I joined and the rules were (very) different way back when...  You'd best edit this question adding the new material — leaving the existing alone.

Comment: The code in `read_file()` is not itself the cause of the leak; it is merely where the memory was allocated that was subsequently not freed.  The trouble is probably that `test_indent()` calls `read_file()` but forgets to `free()` the memory that it was provided.  —— In `read_file()`, you should not increment the space allocated by 1 each time; that becomes expensive.  You should think in terms of doubling the amount of memory allocated each time you need some more — but you have to keep a record of the amount allocated and the amount used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Done - still same issue

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done.  If you're still leaking memory, then you've not fixed the problem in the code that calls `read_file()` properly.  Since you've not (yet) shown that, there's nothing more than a hand-waving answer to be given.  If you simply fixed the pattern of memory allocations, you still need to fix the code in `test_indent()`, or … well, I suspect you don't have access to the source for the higher-level functions; they look like course-supplied test infrastructure.  But maybe `test_indent()` returns the string returned by `read_file()` to the code that calls it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right - I cannot change `test_indent()`. I've changed code in `read_file()`, so it can allocate memory only once, but it still complains about the same issue. Oh, I'm so tired of this exercise... I really don't know what to do and it is the last exercise in this course. The deadline is on 08/31 and I'm just so exhausted...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added code of `test_intend()` to the question...

Comment: You don't do `free(str)` before calling `test_complete()` though you do free it in one of the error paths.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So?

Comment: So what do you think you should do with the value of `str` to free the resources it points to?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `free(str)` in `START_TEST(test_indent)` didn't change anything. I still receive this "`144 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 62 of 66`"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having difficulty believing you. If `free(str);` is added and the code is recompiled, then that should free the string returned by your `indent()` function, or it should double free something, or free something that was bogus (not allocated) — or, I suppose, it could be freeing a null pointer (which is a no-op). You have a `free(str);` in one of the error paths; you're missing it in the other; and you're missing it in the main execution path. If you get a non-null pointer as `str`, adding that `free(str)` should fix something unless you've suppressed something (unlikely).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, edited, recompliled - same. look new `test_indent()` code

Comment: Hmmm, puzzling. I'm at a loss to explain what's going on. Are you sure this is the code being executed? Did you add some other print statements? Did you see the output? If you add a `free(str)` to the program, then that _should_ change the output from `valgrind`. Trying adding one more line: `free((void *)0x12345678);`  —— since this was (almost certainly) not allocated memory, it should generate an error — probably a crash — and some squealing from `valgrind` beforehand. If adding this doesn't affect `valgrind`, then you're not running the program compiled from the source that you're editing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler definitely not running this code...

Comment: OK; then you need to work out what's happening in your build and execution environment so that when you compile code, you're compiling what you've just edited, and when you run code, you're running what you just compiled.  And when those dotted lines have been connected, having the `free(str)` before the `test_complete()` should fix the leak.  Good luck!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The solution was simple as always: I had to add `char *new = input;` at the beginning of the `indent()` and `free(new)` before `return dest;` Thank you very much for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that the code for adding a single character to the output buffer doesn't check whether there's space for the extra character, and there might not be.  You can tickle the bug quicker by using a longer indent (e.g. `" /* Look Ma! */ "`, which is 16 characters).

Where you currently have:

```
        continue;
    } 
    dest[dest_offset++] = c;        
    input++;
}
```

the brute force and carelessness solution adds:

```
        continue;
    }
    if (dest_offset >= dest_len)
    {
        printf("XX: DO = %zu, DL = %zu, PL = %zu, LV = %zu\n", dest_offset, dest_len, pad_len, pad_level);
        putchar('@');fflush(0);
        char *ptr = realloc(dest, dest_len * 2);
        if(!ptr)
        {
            free(dest);
            return NULL;
        }
        dest_len *= 2;
        dest = ptr;
    }
    putchar('.');fflush(0);
    dest[dest_offset++] = c;
    input++;
}
```

Oh, and I left some of the debug code I ended up using on display.  I added quite a lot of vaguely similar printing code.  An assertion at the top of the loop helped, too: `assert(dest_offset <= dest_len);`.  When that went firing, things became clearer (but it took me a while to find out why it was firing).  I also butchered the test in the newline handling code to:

```
        if (dest_offset >= dest_len || (pad_len * pad_level + 1) >= (dest_len - dest_offset))
        {
            printf("YY: DO = %zu, DL = %zu, PL = %zu, LV = %zu\n", dest_offset, dest_len, pad_len, pad_level);
            putchar('@');fflush(0);
            char *ptr = realloc(dest, dest_len * 2);
            if(!ptr)
            {
                free(dest);
                return NULL;
            }
            dest_len *= 2;
            dest = ptr;
        }
```

but that `realloc()` never fired, which was one of the surprises.

I think you need a function to add one character to your output buffer, and you need to wrap up the output buffer control into a structure (`struct Buffer { char *buffer; size_t maxlen; size_t curlen; }` or thereabouts), and you have that one function deal with (re)allocating space as needed.  That will avoid the glaring repeat of the 'brute force and carelessness' solution.  You can make it a `static inline` function if you like — the compiler might avoid some overhead that way without compromising the readability of your code.  There's also a nasty repeat with the two loops to add multiples of the indent to the buffer.  That would be best treated with another function, of course — but it would be different from the 'add one char' in that you can sensibly check for enough space and do the reallocation once.  Or write the function to take a length and pointer to a buffer that is not null terminated (so a single character has length 1 and the padding string has length `pad_len`) and a single function can do the whole lot — probably a better solution.  I'd still package the controls into a structure and let the compiler optimize.

Test `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char data[] = "#include <stdio.h>\nint main(void)\n{\nputs(\"Hello World!\\n\");\nreturn 0;\n}\n";
    printf("Before: [[%s]]\n", data);
    fflush(0);
    char *reformatted = indent(data, " /* Look Ma! */ ");
    printf("Indent: -complete-\n");
    fflush(0);
    printf("Source: [[%s]]\n", data);
    fflush(0);
    printf("Target: [[%s]]\n", reformatted);
    free(reformatted);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've edited my code and question, but there is small issue now... Intend function works perfectly and server says that I've passed this exercise, but now it complains on read_file, but everything seemed to work perfectly...